# Visual studio 2010 crashes every time when opening a solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have a web application in visual studio 2010. visual studio is crash every time when i open the solution and go to design of a specific page in my web application. all the other pages are run smoothly ! problem signaturs are

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  10.0.30319.1
  Application Timestamp:    4ba1fab3
  Fault Module Name:    msenv.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.0.30319.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ba1fd94
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00023169
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Additional information about the problem:

```
LCID:   1033
```

i got this error message " **Unhandled exception at 0x775e45bb in devenv.exe: 0xC015000F: The activation context being deactivated is not the most recently activated one.**" when i debug the error... 
can any one help me regarding this error i m stuck in it....

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps that you can do and maybe gets out of this.

1. on the directory of your project locate the hidden file that have the same name with your project but ends on `.suo`, eg `ProjectName.suo` and delete it.
2. go to your tempo directory and clear it by deleting the files there. To find it type `cd %temp%`
3. Clear the asp.net temporary files located in the subdirectories of `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` called `Temporary ASP.NET Files`
4. if all of the above not work, you can finally clear the class cache of vs. This is located on your personal data folder, under the Application data/microsoft/visualstudio and search there for the directories `ReflectedSchemas` and clear them. VS will be create them again.

From all that the first step will probably solve your issue.

Comment: i have tried that but its not working... there is one specific page in my application that contain AJAX tabs controls .. size of ASPx file is 410 kb and cs file is 136 kb.. when i go to design of that page it crash the visual studio..

Comment: @user681623 Now you change it. You say that is crash every time you start it, now you say that is crash on one page, when you go to design mode. Then DO NOT GO on design mode for that page. This can be happend if the visual studio try to communicate with this tab control and the control crash because is not found some parametre.

Comment: @Aristos.. first it crashes on every start up then i add 
 <httpRuntime
  executionTimeout="90"
 maxRequestLength="6096"/> in my web config. now its load the solution but when ever i go to design its crash..

Comment: @user681623 Then do not go on design mode, do it by hand manual. It crash to me too on some bad design custom controls that throw a lot of errors.